# WHERE claus after JOIN is slowing down my query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

**My Query:**

```
SELECT source.name, file_info.*  
from FILE_INFO  
JOIN source  
ON source.id = file_info.source_ID  
where file_info.source_ID in 
     (select ID from Source where name like 'Donatello.%');
```

**My Tables:**

```
FILE_INFO    
FILE_NAME | FILE_ID | SOURCE_ID | DATE_SEEN | CURRENT_STATUS  

SOURCE  
NAME | ID | CATEGORY
```

**Background:**

In my database, files are associated with the sources who provided them. Each file is given a FILE_ID and each source has a ID (same as SOURCE_ID in table FILE_INFO). However, the table FILE_INFO doesn't hold the name associated with the SOURCE_ID.

I'm trying to print all lines where from the table FILE_INFO along with the respective SOURCE name furthermore, i only want lines where the source providing that file starts with "DONATELLO".

This query works for me, however it runs very slow. Is there a better approach on my code? It works fine until I add that last 'where' clause. When that's included, it runs quite slow.

I appreciate your input.

Comment: You need to look at Explain Plan <http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm> to show what the server is doing. (The link is for Oracle 9 you should use the link for the version you are using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following ?

```
SELECT source.name, file_info.*  
from FILE_INFO  
JOIN source  
ON source.id = file_info.source_ID and source.name like 'Donatello.%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this not be the same?

```
SELECT source.name, file_info.*  
FROM FILE_INFO  
    JOIN source  
        ON source.id = file_info.source_ID  
WHERE source.name like 'Donatello.%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You `IN` clause uses a sub query, and in queries the `source` table again.

Why not simply your SQL as follows?

```
SELECT source.name, file_info.*  
from FILE_INFO  
JOIN source  
ON source.id = file_info.source_ID  
where source.name like 'Donatello.%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on `name` column from `source` table?

Why don't you just write your query like that:

```
SELECT source.name, file_info.*  
from FILE_INFO  
JOIN source  
ON source.id = file_info.source_ID  
where source.name like 'Donatello.%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition to a simple one and invert the table order:

```
SELECT source.name, file_info.*  
from source   
JOIN FILE_INFO
  ON source.id = file_info.source_ID  
where source.name like 'Donatello.%'
```

With indexes in `source(name)` and `file_info(source_ID)`.

This will be faster because the where clause can be spied to the first table in the join table list so indexes can be used with the condition.